# Visual Studio 2017 Xaml intellisense not working with tag "Style"

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have Visual Studio 2017 rel. 15.4.2 with Xamarin 4.7.10.33 (s.o. Windows 7 64 bit).
I create a simple app for Android and iOS and I try to use styles resources.

When I try to define a style inside a ResourceDictionary (in Application.Resources), the intellisense do not show tag "Style".

I have to insert it manually and I don't see nothing oh style's properties.

I see only this [image: this]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you manually code and build it, it works or not? Please have a look at this doc:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/application/, to declare a Style at the application level, in the application's ResourceDictionary using XAML, the default App class must be replaced with a XAML App class and associated code-behind.

Comment: Yes,if I manually code and build it, it works. The problem is only when I try to code the style in XAML App class and associated code-behind. See my images on top: I use XAML App (App.xaml) with associated code-behind (App.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduced this in my side and I have reported it to the VS Product Team to seek for a better support, please check this: [Visual Studio 2017 Xaml intellisense not working with tag “Style”](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/145776/visual-studio-2017-xaml-intellisense-not-working-w.html)
and you can add your comments and vote it, then you can get any updates from the VS Product Team engineers to know the detail progress.